# Selenium on Docker

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I installed Selenium/Hub on docker.
I run it using that command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub
```

I configured tunnel in putty to connect to Selenium via Browser

Unfortunately it doesn't work (i can't connect to selenium via browser) and i don't know why 
Configuration file below:

```
{
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 4444,
  "role": "hub",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "jettyMaxThreads": -1,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "timeout": 30,
  "debug": false
}
```

Why it doesn't work, where can I find logs of selenium docker?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a docker network first, launch a hub, then launch a node for your specific browser to interface with the hub.

```
$ docker network create grid
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --net grid --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.12.0-cobalt
$ docker run -d --net grid -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome:3.12.0-cobalt
$ docker run -d --net grid -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-firefox:3.12.0-cobalt
```

See also the [documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#using-docker-networking).

Comment: I think that You didn't understand me. I have my docker in amazon cloud and i want to connect to selenium docker image on my personal laptop using browser. At the moment i want only connect to selenium administration page in browser. I don't want to do a test.

Comment: Did you set the appropriate security groups in AWS to open port 4444 to your IP?

Comment: Thank You Tom. It was so easy. I forgot about that.